# Mouse event not working while keyboard event is working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javascript game, where the user controls the player with keyboard and mouse, the problem is when the keyboard is being used, the mouse event listeners do not work.

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', _this.addMovements);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', _this.removeMovements);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', _this.updateFaceSideEvent);
    document.addEventListener('click', _this.fireBulletEvent);
```

while the keydown event is working, that time the click event or the mousemove event is not working.

Comment: It is not a Javascript problem, but an OS problem. If the handler functions are correct, then the Javascript is OK. But your OS may have a setting to disable mouse or touchpad while typing. It is true if you have the same problem while moving the mouse and typing in some notepad software.

Comment: I certainly can not recreate your problem. Could you try running just the event listeners and log their output? It is potentially something else in your code that is blocking it.

Comment: Oh btw: please always provide a code snippet that recreates your problem. (if not OS or system related of course)

Comment: Thank you  E. Zacarias and Elias,  it turns out it was an OS problem.